# angular cli doesn't automatically recognize new tests

Tags: javascript, angular

Starting an Angular-cli test via

```
ng test
```

runs only already defined tests. Adding or deleting a test doesn't get automatically recognised (i.e - the test count doesn't change).
Restarting the command refreshes the current test suite, but it takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to make agular-cli automatically recognise new tests?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "*",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json?  I had a similar problem a while ago and it was because i wasn't including one of the ngtools packages

Comment: package.json was generated by angular cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding @ngtools/webpack to your package.json as a dev dependency?

you can use:  `npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack`

If this is a similar problem to what i was facing, it is because saving your source files isn't properly triggering a typescript recompile, and adding @ngtools/webpack should resolve it.

Comment: I just to used your solution but this don't work in my case. My test case is more slow now (from 1 second to 12 second) but if I to do any change in my code the test yet is cached (old code).

Comment: Are you using the same group of packages? And if you use ng serve, does a change in your source files trigger a refresh of the browser with the new changes?

Comment: Yes, I have the same package.json (generated using angular cli), In my case I have not problem when I develop using ng serve. The problem is that ng test use the same test that were loaded in the first time. If I do anything karma is running but the test have the same result that in the first time.

Comment: And if you kill ng test and restart it, the tests that run are now the most current ones?

Comment: That is! I must kill ng test in each change that I do. If I king ng test and restart then I get the last changes.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like the same problem I was facing... Source code changes weren't triggering a typescript recompile. Does that problem happen if you create a brand new clients project?

Comment: I just create a new empty project using angular-cli and I've not the problem. Thanks, I going to research about my problem.